# Dailyrollingfileappender not creating backup of more than 1 day

Tags: log4j

My log config is as follows,but i can see only 1 backup file being created and all the other backup just goes off / deleted.

```
log4j.appender.application=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.application.File=${log.root.path}/test.log
log4j.appender.application.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.application.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.application.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM 
HH\:mm\:ss\:SSS} [%t] %-5p [%c\:%M\:%L]  srcIp=%X{srcIp} - 
remoteHost=%X{remoteHost} -port=%X{port} - activityType=%X{activitytype} - 
activityStatus=%X{activitystatus} -applicationUser=%X{applicationUser} - 
APITXNID=%X{apiTxnId} -CustomerRefNum=%X{CustomerRefNum} -%m%n%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine, there are several thing you could try to do:

1. Try replace `log4j.appender.application.DatePattern` from `'.'yyyy-MM-dd` to `'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm` and see if files would be created every minute. If it works, chances are that some external cleanup script deletes old logs.
2. Add `-Dlog4jdebug.true` to VM options to verify what is effective log4j conf file is used.
3. Also consider using  [API Documentation warning](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

   > DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss. The log4j extras companion includes alternatives which should be considered for new deployments and which are discussed in the documentation for org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

You can have the same effect as your config above, by replacing log4j dependency with [apache-log4j-extras](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17), which implements log4j 1.2.x, but has extra features, such as `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender` with `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`

Then replace in your `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.appender.application=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.application.File=${log.root.path}/test.log
log4j.appender.application.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

with

```
log4j.appender.application=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.application.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.application.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log.root.path}/test.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}
log4j.appender.application.File=${log.root.path}/test.log
```